# Google sheet doesn't trigger any events on .appendRow() from other script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script where a user enters some information and submit. At submit I run an `.appendRow()` which runs successfully. With the data I have, I am trying to set background colors for a number of cells based on the value of another.

Ex. If J2 is then `setBackgroundColor("yellow")` for J2:L2

I created a script attached to the spreadsheet where I'm trying to create a trigger to do it. The trigger I created works when I manually edit the spreadsheet. However neither `onEdit()` nor `onChange()` worked when I `appendRow()`. Does `appendRow()` not trigger an event on the spreadsheet?

Here is my script for the trigger/event.

```
function onEdit(e){
  colorBasedOnStatus(e.range.getRow());
}

function colorBasedOnStatus(rowIndex) {
  Logger.log(rowIndex);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Log");
  var range = sheet.getRange("J"+rowIndex+":L"+rowIndex);
  var values = range.getValues();
  Logger.log(values);
  var status = values[0][0];
  Logger.log("status: " + status);

  range.setFontColor("white");
  if(status === "Denied"){
    range.setBackground("#FF6666");
  } else if(status == "Approved") {
    range.setBackground("#66C285");
  } else {
    range.setBackground("#FFE271");
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Comment: How do users submit their inputs?

Comment: its a script right now that will be a gadget on a google site later

Comment: Then you shouldn't need any trigger... could you show the code you use please?

Comment: I edited the post to include the code

Comment: it was actually the function that appends the row I was interested in... I think you could simply let that script call your "colorBasedOnStatus(rowIndex)" function, without needing any trigger.

Comment: so basically call the ```colorBasedOnStatus(rowIndex)``` after the appendRow and pass the row there?

Comment: I'd say yes... but can't be sure without knowing the code... I see no reason why this wouldn't work though.

Comment: it actually would. i'm pretty new to apps script and have to get used to using scripts in other scripts. thanks for the answer, and i would accept it as an answer if you write it as one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could simply let that script call your `colorBasedOnStatus(rowIndex)` function  without needing any trigger and directly integrated in the function you use to append the new row.

That way you don't need any trigger setup and your code gets simpler too.